# Pascal's other triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Just a brainteaser question: Can you identify the generator of the following pattern of numbers?

[image: Pascal's other triangle]

Remark on any interesting patterns you see in the triangle.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the numbers are the perfect squares $1^2, 2^2, \ldots (n-1)^2$ mod $n$ (starting from $n=2$).

There are an incredible number of patterns/theorems relating to the number/type of quadratic residues mod $n$. Is there something you're curious about specifically?

Comment: You are correct, of course. The reason I posted this is that much like the real Pascal's triangle, there are a lot of visually apparent patterns in the triangle itself. I'll post some visible patterns (with proof) in an answer if no one else has ideas. I did mean this as a soft question (remark about whatever patterns you see); perhaps it should be CW?